# MySQL Select from Two Table Conditionally

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched the net and haven't found anything that exactly fits what I'm needing. I have two tables that are very similar with the exception of one column. Following are the tables:

TABLE case_cards

```
CC_Primary_Num | CC_Num | Fac_ID_Num | Surg_Proc_Num | Fac_Equip_ID_Num |
---------------|--------|------------|---------------|------------------|
         1     |  10001 |     1      |       2       |        4         |
         2     |  10002 |     2      |       3       |        7         |        
         3     |  10002 |     2      |       3       |        2         |
         4     |  10003 |     5      |       7       |        1         |
```

TABLE case_cards_prep

```
CC_Control_Num | CC_Prep_Num | Book_Num | Fac_ID_Num | Surg_Proc_Num | Fac_Equip_ID_Num |
---------------|-------------|----------|------------|---------------|------------------|
         1     |      1      |     1    |     1      |       2       |        9         |
         2     |      2      |     2    |     2      |       3       |        3         |        
         3     |      2      |     2    |     2      |       3       |        5         |
         4     |      3      |     1    |     1      |       2       |        8         |
```

Is it possible to have a Select statement where I am able to pull one or more rows based on the availability of a Book_Num in the case_cards_prep table AND, if so, the largest CC_Prep_Num for the respective Book_Num. If Book_Num not in case_cards_prep, pull the records from the case_cards table for the Surg_Proc_Num? I'm still learning and this one is a bit over my head. Example would be:

IF case_card_prep.Book_Num = 2
THEN Select All Rows
WHERE MAX(CC_Prep_Num)

ELSE Select All Rows
Where Surg_Proc_Num = 3

(obviously not mysql syntax, but you should get the idea... I hope)

RESULTING TABLE

```
Fac_ID_Num | Surg_Proc_Num | Fac_Equip_ID_Num |
-----------|---------------|------------------|
     2     |        3      |         3        |
     2     |        3      |         5        |
```

OR

RESULTING TABLE - If not in case_cards_prep

```
Fac_ID_Num | Surg_Proc_Num | Fac_Equip_ID_Num |
-----------|---------------|------------------|
     5     |        7      |         1        |
```

Comment: I don't follow your logic.  Please reword your question if possible.

Comment: How can you do `WHERE MAX(CC_Prep_Num) ELSE Select All Rows Where Surg_Proc_Num = 3` that's like saying `WHERE MAX(CC_Prep_Num) OR Surg_Proc_Num = 3` which is not logical.  Here is a tip `MAX(CC_Prep_Num)` will be true as long as there is one row, and if there is not a row, you cant select `Surg_Proc_Num = 3`

Comment: For example, say I have a SelectedBooking collection with fields Book_Num and Surg_Proc_Num available. I'd like to search for available equipment using one those two fields as needed. For instance, if SelectedBooking.Book_Num = 2 and SelectedBooking.Surg_Proc_Num = 3, I want to search the case_cards_prep table first for the Book_Num 2 and pull all of the records with the highest CC_Prep_Num for Book_Num 2. If Book_Num 2 is not in case_cards_prep, then search case_cards for matching rows with Surg_Proc_Num. Does that make any sense? Hope so... if not, let me know.

Comment: Otherwise you could do `SELECT  MAX(CC_Prep_Num) FROM case_cards JOIN case_cards_prep ON ( case_cards.CC_Primary_Num = case_cards_prep=CC_Primary_Num OR case_cards_prep.Surg_Proc_Num = 3`

Comment: Neither I can understand your question. Please edit it instead of adding new information in comment.

Answer (score 0):

is this what do you want?

```
SELECT Fac_ID_Num, MAX(CC_Prep_Num), Fac_Equip_ID_Num 
  FROM case_cards_prep 
  GROUP BY Book_Num 
UNION 
SELECT Fac_ID_Num, Surg_Proc_Num, Fac_Equip_ID_Num 
  FROM case_cards 
  WHERE Fac_ID_Num NOT IN (SELECT Fac_ID_Num FROM case_cards_prep )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to select the records based on your booking number.

```
  --Create Table case_cards (CC_Primary_Num int, CC_Num int, Fac_ID_Num int, 
Surg_Proc_Num int, Fac_Equip_ID_Num int)
--Create Table case_cards_prep (CC_Control_Num int, CC_Prep_Num int, Book_Num int, Fac_ID_Num int, Surg_Proc_Num int, Fac_Equip_ID_Num int)
--Delete From case_cards
--Insert Into case_cards
--Select 1, 10001, 1,2,4 Union
--Select 2, 10002, 2,3,7 Union
--Select 3, 10002, 2,3,2 Union
--Select 4, 10003, 5,7,1

--Delete From case_cards_prep
--Insert Into case_cards_prep
--Select 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9 Union
--Select 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 Union
--Select 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5 Union
--Select 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 8
Create PROCEDURE dbo.GetCaseCards --Stored Proc
    @BookNum int = 0 --This is a Variable
AS
--Declare @BookNum int
Declare @CountBook int
Declare @Max int

--Drop Table #Results
Create Table #Results (Fac_ID_Num int, Surg_Proc_Num int, Fac_Equip_ID_Num int)


Select @CountBook = Count(*) From case_cards_prep Where Book_Num = @BookNum
--Select @CountBook
if(@CountBook > 0) 
Begin
    Select @Max = Max(Surg_Proc_Num) From case_cards_prep
    Insert Into #Results
    Select Fac_ID_Num, Surg_Proc_Num, Fac_Equip_ID_Num From case_cards_prep Where Surg_Proc_Num = @Max

End
if(@CountBook = 0) 
Begin
    Insert Into #Results
    Select Fac_ID_Num, Surg_Proc_Num, Fac_Equip_ID_Num From case_cards Where Right(CC_Num,1) = @BookNum

End

Select * From #Results
```

Execute the procedure by using the following:

```
Exec GetCaseCards 2
Exec GetCaseCards 3
```